# Installing dependency for cocos2dx on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, dependencies

Getting error while trying to install dependency for cocos2dx v4.0 on ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Output -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gpgv or
                gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv1 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3.1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not installable
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 base-files : PreDepends: awk
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 base-passwd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libdebconfclient0 (>= 0.145) but it is not going to be installed
 bash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
            PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: bsdextrautils
 coreutils : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.44) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.2.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 dash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 debianutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 diffutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 dpkg : PreDepends: libbz2-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libcom-err2 (>= 1.43.9) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libss2 (>= 1.38) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: logsave
             Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 findutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 grep : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
        PreDepends: libpcre3 but it is not going to be installed
 gzip : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 hostname : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.35) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
 libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
 login : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
 ncurses-bin : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
               PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6.3) but it is not going to be installed
 perl-base : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not going to be installed
 sed : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
               Depends: mokutil (>= 0.3.0+1538710437.fb6250f-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: sbsigntool but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: secureboot-db but it is not going to be installed
 sysvinit-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
 tar : PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.23) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
       PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libcap-ng0 (>= 0.7.9) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsmartcols1 (>= 2.34) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
              PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: No, but thanks for the try.